# Buffer overflow не исполняется на стеке даже при компиляции с -z execstack

Tags: linux, c, gcc

Пытаясь постигнуть buffer overflow, столкнулся с проблемой:
У меня получилось перезаписать `rip`, в него я записываю адрес инструкции `jmp rax`, чтобы программа начала выполнять инструкции со стека, но, когда она переходит в поледовательность `nop` инструкций, вместо их выполнения, вылетает с ошибкой

```
Stopped reason: SIGSEGV
0x0000000090909090 in ?? ()
```

Хотя, если я вместо адреса `rax` запишу в `rip` адрес переменной среды, в которую я поместил шелл код, то все сработает.

Что я делаю не так?

Код "уязвимой" программы:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(char *bar)
{
    int loggedin = 0;
    char password[50];
    strcpy(password, bar);
    if(strcmp(password, "secur3")==0)
    {
         loggedin = 1;
    }
    return loggedin;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    if(foo(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("\n\nLoggedin\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nLogin Failed!\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Компилирую с параметрами

```
-fno-stack-protector -z execstack
```

ASLR отключена

сам шеллкод:

```
xor eax, eax
mov rbx, 0xFF978CD091969DD1
neg rbx
push rbx
push rsp
pop rdi
cdq
push rdx
push rdi
push rsp
pop rsi
mov al, 0x3b
syscall
```

Взят отсюда http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-806.php

Comment: Судя по `0x0000000090909090`, вы перешли _по адресу_ 0x0000000090909090, а не не такой _код_.

Comment: Дайте ваш шеллкод, без него непонятно.

Comment: Ну и кроме того, попробуйте отладить ваш код в gdb, он-то видит лучше, куда именно вы переходите.

Comment: Да, и не пробовали ли вы запустить в отладчике, что бы увидеть что реально в регистрах и стеке и куда вы реально переходите

Comment: Я  как раз сейчас там и отлаживаю. Запускаю с параметром, генерирующим шеллкод: $(python -c "print('''\x31\xc0\x48\xbb\xd1\x9d\x96\x91\xd0\x8c\x97\xff\x48\xf7\xdb\x53\x54\x5f\x99\x52\x57\x54\x5e\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05'''+'''\x90'''*45+'''\x27\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00''')")

Comment: Шеллкод в ассемблерном виде в текст вопроса поместите. мне например его дизассемблировать влом

Comment: Я поэтому и решил сделать так, чтобы в `rip` был адрес `rax`, потому что `rax` после входа в функцию указывает на шеллкод

Comment: @Mike: И не только вам.

Comment: Я воспользовался этим http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-806.php

Comment: Но кроме дизассемблированного вида нужен, по идее, и бинарный.

Comment: То есть, вы предлагаете нам найти ошибку в шеллкоде, который вы даже не разобрали? Ай-яй-яй. Ну так дизассемблируйте, всё равно без этого никак. Это нужно сделать или вам, или нам.

Comment: @VladD он прекрасно работает, если я помещаю его в переменную среды export PWN=`python -c 'print "\x31\xc0\x48\xbb\xd1\x9d\x96\x91\xd0\x8c\x97\xff\x48\xf7\xdb\x53\x54\x5f\x99\x52\x57\x54\x5e\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05"'` и в `rip` записываю адрес этой переменной, так что в нем, вероятно, нет ошибки

Comment: Ваш питон как минимум генерит кучу NOP, я не вижу по приведенной вами ссылке ни одного NOP. Весь шеллкод в ассемблерном виде поместите в _текст вопроса_. Как мы по вашему должны по этой питоновской строке догадаться, как вообще в rax попадает какой то там адрес

Comment: Вы так и не поняли, вызов sh совершенно не интересен ... Вы не привели в ассемблерном виде то, что у вас попадает в стек, то что должно обеспечить переход на шеллкод

Comment: @EdwardDankovsky: Это понятно, но вопрос в том, как нужному адресу попасть в rip.

Comment: @VladD возможно я вас неправильно понимаю, но судя по тому, что происходит в gdb, как раз за счет этого переполнения буфера у меня перезаписывается тот адрес в стеке, который извлекается инструкцией `ret` после завершения функции

Comment: А по этому адресу находится инструкция `jmp rax`

Comment: Ну так это то элементарно. посмотрите в ассемблерном виде вашу C программу. Если я правильно понимаю поведение стека в C-вызовах, то при входе в foo из RSP вычитается 54 или около того, что бы зарезервировать место под loggedin и password. Значит вы пишете строку что бы переполнить эти 54 байта и прямо за ними в стеке оказался нужный вам адрес, что бы при выполнении ret из foo произошел переход по этому адресу

Comment: @Mike да, именно это и происходит, но дальше, на сколько я понимаю,  программа должна выполнять инструкции по этому адресу, но вместо этого она, судя по всему, воспринимает инструкции, как адреса или что-то подобное и пытается перейти по ним, вот я и не могу понять почему так происходит

Comment: Так, ret как известно извлекает из стека адрес возврата и переходит по нему, т.е. ее по факту можно рассматривать как `pop rip` она тупо помещает в rip адрес который оказывается на вершине стека на момент ее выполнения. И там должен лежать адрес который _указывает_ на некий исполнимый, нужный вам код. У меня ощущение, что вы в стек пишете эти самые NOP, которые и заносятся в RIP и она пытается перейти по адресу 0x90.. а там должны лежать не эти 90, а некий адрес где лежат те самые 90

Comment: @Mike проверил в gdb c утилитой "peda". Перед `ret` первым на стеке лежит адрес `0x400527`, по которому распологается инструкция `jmp rax`. `0x7fffffffdd78 --> 0x400527 (<deregister_tm_clones+39>: jmp    rax)`

Comment: Хорошо, а что у вас в это время в rax ?

Comment: Единственно, чего я не понимаю в этих переполнениях... А CS во время выполнения программы равен SS ?

Comment: @Mike `rax            0x90909090 0x90909090` вот что пишет gdb

Comment: Ну вот, `jmp rax` по факту `mov rip,rax`. Вот вы и переходите по адресу 0x9090... Если уж там лежит `jmp rax`, то в rax должен быть адрес в котором расположен ваш шеллкод. ну или _вместо_ `jmp rax` должен быть сам shell код, если там места для него хватает и его ничто не затирает

Comment: @Mike ясно, я думал, что это инструкция исполнит то, что находится в rax, как функцию. Спасибо больше. А не подскажите ли еще, есть ли способ вызвать мой шелл код, подобным образом, я имею в виду не используяю прямых адресов?

Comment: нет, только прямые адреса, так что немного не так скомпиленная программа и по нужным адресам совершенно не то что нужно

Comment: @Mike Спасибо ещё раз

Comment: @Mike: Вы бы оформили этот диалог в ответ, а?

Comment: @EdwardDankovsky: насколько мне помнится, там flat-модель, да, все адреса абсолютные и не зависят от селектора. Сегмент имел значение в DOS-овской адресации.

Comment: @VladD Да, можно наверное попробовать ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуем разобраться, как работают те самые Stack Overflow так удачно вынесенные в название нашего сообщества :)

Перед нами код программы на C, в которой программист не проверяет длину строки при ее копировании. Да, в нашем случае это просто демонстрационный пример, но к сожалению так часто происходит даже в известных, распространенных программах...

Итак, мы видим, программа взяла некий параметр из командной строки `argv[1]` и передала его в функцию `foo()`, которая копирует его, не проверяя длины строки в переменную `password`, под которую выделено 50 байт. Что значит 'выделено' - в C программах для всех локальных переменных резервируется место в стеке программы. Стек - это специальная область памяти, где программа хранит различные временные переменные и куда, при вызове функций, процессор сохраняет адрес, куда должна вернутся программа, после выполнения данной функции. Стек имеет интересную особенность, при добавлении в него чего либо, он растет от старших адресов в памяти к младшим. При входе в функцию `foo()` первым делом выделяется место под локальные переменные, для этого указатель текущей ячейки стека (`RSP`) уменьшается на размер этих переменных. В нашем случае там две переменные, общей длиной 54 байта. Вот так *примерно* выглядит стек, когда начинает выполнятся первый оператор в `foo()` (`strcpy`):

```
RSP -> password ... 50 байт
       loggedin ... 4 байта
       "адрес возврата" 4 байта
Addr:  параметры функции, переменные main(), свободная область
```

Итак, злоумышленник, зная, что у нас так криво написана функция передает нам в поле для пароля строку немного длиннее тех 50 байт, которые мы под него зарезервировали. мы, ничего не подозревая, вызываем функцию strcpy которая копирует переданную нам строку по указанному нами адресу, т.е. в переменную password. Она пишет 50 байт ... Но строка еще не кончилась ... Она пишет еще 4 байта, которые попадают в loggedin (кстати, записав туда 1 уже можно пройти авторизацию не зная пароля :) ) ... Строка не кончилась ... Тут в этой строке лежит некое число, которое злоумышленник заранее подобрал (видя нашу программу) и которое по факту является адресом точки `Addr` из приведенного образца стека... Далее в строке лежат выполнимые инструкции процессора, которые хочет выполнить злоумышленник (приведены в вопросе, в виде ассемблерного кода, по факту запускающего `/bin/sh`). На этом строка заканчивается и радостная, ничего не подозревающая функция `strcpy` (об этом должен заботится программист) завершается, испортив и адрес возврата и еще кусок стека.

Функция `foo()` наконец завершается, и пытается вернутся туда, откуда ее вызвали, для этого она выполняет инструкцию процессора `ret`, которая достает из стека `"адрес возврата"` и по нему переходит, т.е. процессор начинает выполнять инструкции по этому адресу. А злоумышленник положил туда (нашими же руками) как раз адрес продолжения стека, куда скопировал свой зловредный код ...

Собственно все, код в стеке выполняется, злоумышленник радуется, мы кусаем локти и думаем как же он забрался к нам в систему ...

Автор вопроса выяснил, что было "не так", в переписке к вопросу, он просто немного не так ощущал ход выполнения программы.

А мы узнали про механику того самого Stack Overflow ... И поняли, на сколько важно проверять *все* передаваемые параметры. Конкретно в данном примере всего лишь надо было использовать `strncpy` которая принимает 3й аргумент - максимальную длину копируемой строки. То же касается и других языков программирования, вот такие небольшие небрежности приводят к взломам века ...

Comment: Разве компилятор не выпилит `loggedin` из-за её сомнительной полезности?

Comment: @Qwertiy почему сомнительной, она ретурнится из функции. хотя конечно может регистром сделать

Comment: Потому что `int foo(char *bar)
{
    char password[50];
    strcpy(password, bar);
    if(strcmp(password, "secur3")==0)
         return 1;
    return 0;
}` не говоря о том, что тут ещё кучу всего можно наоптимизировать, в том числе, заинлайнить функцию.

Comment: Предполагается, что атакующий это подробно изучит, он же дложен все равно все адреса точно узнать. не говоря уже о том, что вариант с strcpy проблематично взломать так что бы заставить выполняться свой код, потому как этот код не должен содержать ни одного 0.